# Getting the presentation size inside a PowerPoint add-in

Tags: c++, powerpoint, add-in

I have a PowerPoint addin (c++) and I'm looking for a way to get the current presentation size. when I open a presentation and go to the File tab I can see that the size is displayed under the list of the built in document properties.

So inside the addin I enumerated all the built in document properties, but there is no "Size" property. the only relevant property is "Number of bytes" but it doesn't have a value.

I also didn't find any relevant property of the [Presentation object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746640.aspx).

How can I get the presentation size inside the addin?

Comment: If you navigate down the Presentation object, you will get PageSetup which properties which expose the size information of the presentation.

Comment: PageSetup defines the size - dimensions - of the slides (A3, A4 etc.) - not related to file size...

Comment: You can get the size of the file on disk by asking the OS to tell you how large ActivePresentation.Fullpath is, but that won't reflect any changes made since the last save.

Comment: My mistake in misreading the question. What Steve said.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to  get the presentation size in the Presentation object but other work around which you can do is use the File object to get the file size.

```
// Create new FileInfo object and get the Length.
string fileName = Presentation.FullName;   // from the presentation object
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fileName);
long s1 = f.Length;
```